# Powershell regex with an excluded pattern (guid)

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

I am trying to find all occurances of text that look like this:

`log.Error("{something other than guid formatted string}")`

e.g., this would be a postive match:

`log.Errog("some message")`

and this would not match

`log.Error("4e6c1b55-67a7-448d-a5fe-8c9fb8a31371")`

I have the following, which works the *opposite* as I intend, which is to say it successfully finds the instances with the guid:

```
$positiveMatch = "log.Error(`"some message`")"
$negativeMatch = "log.Error(`"4e6c1b55-67a7-448d-a5fe-8c9fb8a31371`""
$pattern = "log\.Error\(`"[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}`""

[regex]::matches($positiveMatch, $pattern)
[regex]::matches($negativeMatch, $pattern)
```

My attempt to inverse this is failing for both strings:

```
$pattern = "log\.Error\(`"?![a-fA-F0-9]{8}?!-?!([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}?![a-fA-F0-9]{12}`""
```

How do I get a list of all `log.Error("` that do not contain a guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion like below,

```
log\.Error\("(?![a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}")[^"]*"\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/5)

And don't forget to escape the double quotes if necessary.

To get this working in powershell, and to allow additional content at the end of the line (e.g. `log.Error("some message", "additional params")`, the pattern would look like this:

```
$pattern = "log\.Error\(`"(?![a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}`")"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  For anyone else reading this, the proper escape for powershell you need to use backtick to escape the internal double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was tagged [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell): in PowerShell you'd use [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) with the `-NotMatch` parameter:

```
PS C:\> $pattern = 'log\.error\("[a-f0-9]{8}-([a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}"\)'
PS C:\> @'
>> log.Error("some message")
>> other text
>> log.Error("4e6c1b55-67a7-448d-a5fe-8c9fb8a31371")
>> log.Error("{something other than guid formatted string}")
>> 4e6c1b55-67a7-448d-a5fe-8c9fb8a31371
>> '@ -split "`n" | Select-String $pattern -NotMatch | select -Expand Line
>>
log.Error("some message")
other text
log.Error("{something other than guid formatted string}")
4e6c1b55-67a7-448d-a5fe-8c9fb8a31371
```